# Checking conditions with a function django views

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make my code more readable and less verbose.
I have this long view, where I have some if and elif statement to check some conditions. What I am trying to do is to write this function into another file (utils.py) and use this function in the views.
The view is something like that:
views.py

```
        if float(ata_tacho) <= float(etd_tacho):
            messages.error(request, "ATA Tachometer cannot be greater or equal to ETD Tachometer")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight:add_new_flight'))
        elif ata <= etd:
            messages.error(request, "ATA cannot be greater or equal to ETD!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight:add_new_flight'))

        elif function_type_obj.name == 'Dual Command' and not instructor:
            messages.error(request, "Instructor must be on Board!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight:add_new_flight'))
More code to run only if conditions above are satisfied
```

These are some conditions I need to check to continue running the code. So far, so good.
If I try to write this function in a more general one in utils.py file like below:

utils.py

```
def flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type, instructor):
    if float(ata_tacho) <= float(etd_tacho):
         messages.error(request, "ATA Tachometer cannot be greater or equal to ETD Tachometer")
         return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    elif ata <= etd:
        messages.error(request, "ATA cannot be greater or equal to ETD!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    elif function_type == 'Dual Command' and not instructor:
        messages.error(request, "Instructor must be on Board!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

And I call the function in the view like this:

```
        flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type_obj.name, instructor)
```

What happens is that basically this piece of code works but DOES NOT stop the rest of the view to keep its job done. I mean, it returns the error messages but doesn't stop the rest of the view. I think I am probably missing some return or I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you just call the `flight_validator` that way, its return value is just ignored.

A quick fix could be:

`views.py`:

```py
redirection = flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type_obj.name, instructor)

if redirection is not None:
    return redirection
```

**Alternative 1:**

But this is probably a best practice to keep the HTTP response initialized in the views.

`utils.py`:

```
def flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type, instructor):
    if float(ata_tacho) <= float(etd_tacho):
        messages.error(request, "ATA Tachometer cannot be greater or equal to ETD Tachometer")
        return False
    elif ata <= etd:
        messages.error(request, "ATA cannot be greater or equal to ETD!")
        return False
    elif function_type == 'Dual Command' and not instructor:
        messages.error(request, "Instructor must be on Board!")
        return False

    return True
```

`views.py`:

```py
is_valid_flight = flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type_obj.name, instructor)

if not is_valid_flight:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight:add_new_flight'))
```

**Alternative 2:**

That been said, you could even factor a bit more:

`utils.py`:

```
def flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type, instructor):
    if float(ata_tacho) <= float(etd_tacho):
        return False, "ATA Tachometer cannot be greater or equal to ETD Tachometer"
    elif ata <= etd:
        return False, "ATA cannot be greater or equal to ETD!"
    elif function_type == 'Dual Command' and not instructor:
        return False, "Instructor must be on Board!"

    return True, ""
```

`views.py`:

```py
is_valid_flight, error_message = flight_validator(request, ata_tacho, etd_tacho, ata, etd, function_type_obj.name, instructor)

if not is_valid_flight:
    messages.error(request, error_message)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('flight:add_new_flight'))
```